# Using Microsoft.office.interop.word in sharepoint server

Tags: sharepoint, ms-word, office-interop, event-receiver

So I really need to run word and microsoft.office.interop.word on a sharepoint server. There are no replacement libraries that it is possible to use in order to gain this functionality in order to get the following code to work.

```
   string filenameopen = @"C:\tmp\file.docx";

    Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();


    properties.ListItem["Title"] = "1725";
    properties.ListItem.Update();
    Word.Document document = wordApp.Documents.Open(filenameopen);
    int commentscount = document.Comments.Count;
    int revisionscount = document.Revisions.Count;
    document.ActiveWindow.Close();
    wordApp.Application.Quit(-1);
```

Would anyone be able to tell me a viable workaround for this.

If you are going to say "You should not use Word (a desktop application for users) in a server process (headless). " or words to that effect, please do not comment here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word in Sharepoint environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52225264/using-microsoft-office-interop-word-in-sharepoint-environment)

Comment: Even though you don't want to believe it, as evidenced by your reaction yesterday https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52225264/using-microsoft-office-interop-word-in-sharepoint-environment, it is possible to get this infomation using libraries that work directly with the Open XML file format, without attempting to run Word in a server environment. This is exactly the scenario the file format and the SDK were developed for. It *IS* possible. If Word should "hang" while requesting user input - something Word does regularly - there will be no way to dismiss / answer that demand with no monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft recommends against installing those libraries on your server. Use OpenXML and the SharePoint CSOM API instead.